# Msg: Create a master key in the database or open the master key - VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish

I am trying to publish my project in VS 2012 to an existing 2005 sql database. My publish failed and I am getting the following error:

(214,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15581, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the database you're trying to push data to is encrypted or not?  I expect it's either using full TDE across the whole database, or alternatively colum-level encryption on some of the data in some of the tables.    Use `SELECT *
FROM sys.databases
WHERE is_encrypted = 1` to check to see if there are any databases encrypted entirely